# New API in Azure API management

Tags: azure-api-management

I've created an instance of the API gateway and added my API to it via an OpenAPI spec. I can invoke the API properly via the 'Test' tab.

When I try to view the API in the developer portal, I get a 500 error when I try to view the operations I added. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: You could attach browser console logs to make the error clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to API which is getting error and check the settings. you should observe that the **Web service URL** is missing. Add the URL over there and try to test again. 500 internal server error is because of the missing URL.

Answer (score 0):

Found that I needed to specify the 'Web service URL' to the internal load balancer for my API's. I did not realize this was not populated in the swagger file.